# read/write vector of custom objects to/from file

Tags: c++, file, vector

I am writting code to write a vector of "person" objects to a file and then read the file. I am getting correct output, but at the end of the main() function iI am getting error " unhandled exception writing location ......"
What am I doing wrong, how to debug such error ?
here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class person{
public:
    string name;
    int age;


 person(){

 }
 person(string name,int age){
     this->name= name;
     this->age = age;

 }

  virtual void display(){

       cout << name <<" "<< age << endl;
  }

};



int main () {

fstream f;
f.open("amu.txt",ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc);
if(f){
    cout<<"file found"<<endl;
}
else{
    cout<<"file not found"<<endl;
    terminate();
}

// creating a vector
vector<person> per;

//populating with "person" objects

for(int i=0;i<100;i=i+10)
{
    person amu("ameykamat",i);
    per.push_back(amu);
}

//wrting objects from vector to the file

for(vector<person>::iterator itr = per.begin(); itr != per.end() ; ++itr)
    {

    f.write((char *)&(*itr),sizeof(*itr));

    }

// taking curson to the start of the file

    f.seekg(0,ios::beg);

//creating temp obj for printing from file
    person amu;
    while(f.read((char *)&amu, sizeof(amu))){
    cout<<(amu.name).c_str()<<" "<<(amu.age)<<endl;
}


   f.close();

system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `person` is not trivially copyable, this cannot work.

Comment: what does "trivially copyable" means?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable

Comment: `f.write((char *)&(*itr),sizeof(*itr));` is fundamentally broken as the `std::string name` member in each `person` object likely contain pointers to dynamically allocated ("heap") memory that actually stores the textual content.  You save the pointer values, but the string content won't be there at those virtual addresses if you reload the pointer values from another process (even another instance/run of the same program).  Save the text itself into the file ala: `f << itr->age << ' ' << itr->name << '\n;', then read ala `while (f >> amu.age && std::getline(f, amu.name)) ...use amu...`.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::string` if not a simple `char[]` : nothing proves that when you copy from its address with a length of sizeof(std::string) you actually copy the data. The standard implementation uses dynamic allocation so you can almost be sure that you will not copy actual data this way !

You should instead imagine a serialization format (for example : age, length of name, null terminated character array for name), but you should also look for references at [Serialization and Unserialization](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/serialization.html) in the C++ FAQ.

Provide it will only run on one single machine (or same type of machine) and same compiler (ie no architecture change problem), you could implement that way :

```
class person {
   ...
    ostream& write(ostream& os) {
        int l = name.length();
        os.write((const char *) &age, sizeof(age));
        os.write((const char *) &l, sizeof(size_t));
        os.write(name.c_str(), name.length());
        return os;
    }

    istream& read(istream& is) {
        int l;
        is.read((char *) &age, sizeof(age));
        if(! is.eof()) {
            is.read((char *) &l, sizeof(size_t));
            if (! is.eof()) {
                char* n = new char[l];
                is.read(n, l);
                name.assign(n,l);
                delete[] n;
            }
        }
        return is;
    }
}
```

and then use :

```
for(vector<person>::iterator itr = per.begin(); itr != per.end() ; ++itr)
    {
    itr->write(f);
    }
...
while(! amu.read(f).eof()){
    cout<<(amu.name).c_str()<<" "<<(amu.age)<<endl;
}
```